# view not found in Passing ID on create function on laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to pass the `user_id` on create page.

My `controller`

```
public function create($user)
{

    $loanAmount=LoanAmount::all()->pluck('amount','id');
    $userId=User::where('id',$user)->pluck('id')->first();
    // $user->id;
    // dd($user);
    return view('loan/grant-loan-amounts/create/'.$userId)
                ->with($userId)
                ->with($loanAmount);
}
```

Here's my `route`

```
Route::resource('loan/grant-loan-amounts', 'Loan\\GrantLoanAmountsController',[
    'except' => ['create']
]);
Route::get('loan/grant-loan-amounts/create/{userId}', 'Loan\\GrantLoanAmountsController@create')->name('grant-loan-amounts.create');
```

I made the create page blank. with only "asd" to display.

what I want to achieve is that, from user list which is on user folder, I'll pass the user id on grant loan amount create a page. But I can't figure out why the route can't be found.

any suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't seem a route problem... I think the problem is `return view('loan/grant-loan-amounts/create/'.$userId)`... I don't think you have a view foreach user id in you database (something like 1.blade.php, 2.blade.php and so on)

Comment: i believe you want to redirect user to that loan amounts route which will return the view so you can do that simply by using `redirect` method try this `return redirect()->route(''grant-loan-amounts.create", $userId)
                ->with($userId)
                ->with($loanAmount); `

Comment: hi @SalmanZafar this gives me the error, ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Illegal offset type

Comment: Hi @IlGala yes I don't have a for each. I just need to grab the id of the user so that I can put it on hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the id in the first parameter of `view()` function. Only mention the view file in the first parameter of the view function. Pass all variables with `compact()` function as the second parameter of `view()`. Example:

```
public function create($user)
{
    $loanAmount=LoanAmount::all()->pluck('amount','id');
    $userId=User::query()->findOrFail($user)->id;

    return view('user.create',compact('userId','loanAmount')) //in this example 'user' is the folder and 'create' is the file inside user folder
}
```

Comment: Putting compact actually works. This is what my return view looks like now, "return view('loan.grant-loan-amounts.create', compact('userId','loanAmount'));"

Answer (score 0):

Because you have this route:

```php
Route::get('loan/grant-loan-amounts/create/{userId}', 'Loan\\GrantLoanAmountsController@create')->name('grant-loan-amounts.create');
```

You named the route so you should call it by it's name:

```php
return redirect()->route('grant-loan-amounts.create', $userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

pluck required one more parameter for fetch data.

```
public function create($user)
{

$loanAmount=LoanAmount::all()->pluck('amount','id');
$userId=User::findOrFail($user);
return view('YourBladeFileFolderLocationOrFileLocationHere')->compact('userId','loanAmount');
}
```

now you can fetch or write at blade file like 
For Id : 
{{ $userId->id }}

For User Name : 
{{ $userId->name }}